# What the heck is going on with this AD filter in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I [recently wrote this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/465832/10472) and stumbled on something interesting.

`get-aduser -filter {-not (description -eq "auto")} | measure-object`

and

`get-aduser -filter {description -ne "auto"} | measure-object`

return two very different things when run against the same data, with the first command returning the expected value. It appears at first glance that users with a null value in the description field are *not* returned in as matches in the second command, even though NULL clearly doesn't equal "auto".

A couple of people in chat have looked at this and verified that I'm not insane. What's going on here?

Comment: Interesting that piping it through Where-object and applying the filter that doesn't work above works.  get-aduser -filter * -Properties description| ?{$_.description -ne "Auto"} | measure

Comment: @Mike Yes, this appears to be behavior of the `-ne` comparison operator *within* the `-Filter` block only. Specifically, when the input value of the comparison is `$null`.

Comment: Like and notlike seem to work similarly.  {description -notlike "something"}  does not work, but {-not (description -like "something")} does.  Also the one that works takes considerably longer to evaluate.  Like the broken one isn't evaluating all the objects it should.

Comment: @Mike That's right. I actually stumbled on this using `-notlike` originally, but switched to `-ne` after I realized I wasn't getting what I wanted. TBH, I forgot I had even tried that until you mentioned it - but I can reproduce it as well.

Comment: get-aduser -filter { -not (description -ne 'auto') } will also give wrong results (both 'auto' and empty). I would suggest using LDAPFilter instead. Two reasons: it works as expected (try -LDAPFilter '(!(description=auto))') and it's portable to any other tool. In -filter you have to use real attributes anyway, so you are half way there... ;) Can't really see any reason "why"...

Comment: Right, it seems that `-ne` or `-notlike` don't play nice

Comment: Just a thought but maybe PoSH's `-eq`/`-ne` clause tries to behave like a SQL `=`/`<>`?  In SQL, `foo = NULL` and `foo <> NULL` will always return false, because NULL is 'incomparable' -- only the `foo IS NULL` and `foo IS NOT NULL` special operators will work.  The behaviour must be similar in PoSH, where your `-not (foo -eq "bar")` filter would return everything for which `(foo -eq "bar")` returned `$false`, which `foo -eq $null` would do.  Instead, how about `if (!foo -or foo -ne "bar")` (equivalent SQL `foo IS NULL OR foo <> 'bar'`)?

Comment: @jimbobmcgee Both of these return `$true` in PowerShell:  `$null -ne "horse"` and `"horse" -ne $null`.

Comment: @jscott :: Yes, *normally* in an `if` test, but I think `-Filter` is different (if only for the AD 'module') -- I'm betting it parses it as an Expression tree and builds an actual query.  I'm betting that, in the native query language (LDAP or ADSI/WQL), `foo = NULL` equates to false.  The charactaristics are too much like SQL NULL equation to be anything else, in my mind.

Comment: As a general rule in PowerShell, "Filter" parameters are defined to operate in the native context/syntax of the command.  In this case, I believe that means that the PowerShell syntax is being converted under the covers to LDAP query language (as @jimbobmcgee posited).

See the help for the parameter and the LDAPFilter parameter (which specifies they have the same feature set).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key difference between the two is the first command does not involve a direct comparison of values to get all the results, and the second command does.  The first command includes NULL results and the second one does not (as MDMarra already discovered).  Both commands start with this cmdlet:

```
get-aduser
```

When going through the below, remember that the results of this cmdlet include all AD users regardless of anything else in the `-filter` parameter after it.

Now let's break down the two parts that are different.  The first one:

```
{-not (description -eq "auto")}
```

...means

1. "figure out where the description attribute ***equals*** the text
   string "auto". For this comparison to work, a string needs to exist
   in the description field for the `-eq` operator to be able to compare it
   to "auto". NULL values are dropped from this comparison since it can't compare a NULL to a string value.
2. **independently of the** `-eq` **filter parameter** give me EVERYTHING that is NOT the result of `(description -eq "auto")`, which will include NULLs, because the original cmdlet, `get-aduser`, includes all AD users. It did not have to compare anything to anything else with the `-not` operator.  It just gave you everything besides what the results of the `(description -eq "auto")` filter were.

In your example suppose you have 1 AD user that has their description equal to "auto", a few hundred with something other than "auto" and a few hundred with NULL descriptions.  Stepping through the command logic it will do:

1. Give me all AD users (get-aduser) where the description
   equals "auto" - results in 1 user
2. Give me all the AD users that are NOT what you just gave me -
   result is the few hundred with something else AND the few hundred
   that have NULL.

Since it didn't have to compare anything to anything else using the `-not` operator, the result included the NULL description users that were captured in the original `get-aduser` cmdlet.

The second command:

```
{description -ne "auto"}
```

...means

1. "figure out where the description attribute ***does not equal*** the exact string "auto".  Again, for this comparison to work, a string needs to exist
   in the description field for the `-ne` operator to be able to compare it
   to "auto". NULL values are dropped from this comparison since it can't compare a NULL to a string value.

In your example again suppose you have 1 AD user that has their description equal to "auto", a few hundred with something other than "auto" and a few hundred with NULL descriptions.  Stepping through the command logic it will do:

1. Give me all AD users where the description is not equal to "auto" - results in the few hundred users with the something other than "auto" in their description.
   It doesn't pull the users with NULL descriptions because it can't compare a NULL to a text string.

Either way the whole difference between the two commands is definitely non-intuitive.

Using this command you should be able to catch the NULLs with an "-and" in there too like this:

```
{description -ne "auto" -and description -ne $NULL}
```

I'm not 100% on the syntax since I can't test it right now, and there is probably a better way to do it than this too.  When it's all broken down it is fairly anti-climatic and took a lot of typing to explain, but I've run into weird stuff like this before using the various operators and a lot of trial and error since I can never remember all the caveats that go along with using each one.

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx:

> **Comparison Operators**
>
> Use comparison operators (-eq, -ne, -gt, -lt, -le, -ge) to compare
>   values and test conditions. ***For example, you can compare two string
>   values to  determine whether they are equal.***
>
> The comparison operators include the match operators (-match,
>   -notmatch),  which find patterns by using regular expressions; the replace operator  (-replace), which uses regular expressions to change
>   input values; the like operators (-like, -notlike), which find
>   patterns using wildcard  characters (*); and the containment operators
>   (in, -notin, -contains, 
>   -notcontains), which determine whether a test value appears in a reference set.
>
> They also include the bitwise operators (-bAND, -bOR, -bXOR, -bNOT) to
>   manipulate the bit patterns in values.
>
> For more information, see about_Comparison_Operators
>
> **Logical Operators**
>
> **Use logical operators (-and, -or, -xor, -not, !) to connect conditional statements into a single complex conditional**. For
>   example, you can use a logical -and operator to create an object
>   filter with two different  conditions.
>
> For more information, see about_Logical_Operators.

Comment: Good overview for sure, but why are null values excluded from the -ne and -notlike operators? That's the real head scratcher. I'm wondering if its by design an has some esoteric .net spec explanation or if its a bug or unexpected behavior?

Comment: Wait, just read more closely. It looks like they only compare strings and null attributes are actually null and not an empty string. Interesting if unintuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this old question as it comes up when searching:

Using -Filter with negative match such as -ne or -notlike excludes results with empty null values.
For them to be included you also need to explicitly match using **-notlike '*'** as **-eq ''** and **-eq $NULL** are not valid filters. Note this is a quirk with -Filter, using a direct -LdapFilter DOES negative match empty values.

Here is a Filter and LdapFilter example of multi match with negative:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { mail -like '*example*' -and (description -ne 'example' -or description -notlike '*') }

Get-ADUser -LdapFilter '(&(mail=*example*)(!description=example))'
```